# Can't write to external storage from a NotificationPublisher

Tags: java, android, file-writing

I'm having a problem with writing a File from a NotificationPublisher in Android studio. When I try to write it I get a "Android open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)" error.

I do have the permissions in my manifest to read and write to external storage. I also have the NotificationPublisher as receiver in the manifest. I have  written other files to this specific directory and those worked. I pass the Directory into which the file should be written as an extra in the intent:

```
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay, File directory) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.DIRECTORY, directory);
    Toast.makeText(this, directory.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

It is the right directory, I checked with a toast. Within the NotificationPublisher I unpack the directory and try to write to an existing (but empty) file:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String DIRECTORY = "directory";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    File directory = intent.getParcelableExtra(DIRECTORY);

    final File file = new File(directory, "received.txt");
    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append("True");

        myOutWriter.close();

        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
```

Do any of you have an idea what the problem might be?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact value of `directory`? Where did you get it?

Comment: @CommonsWare It gets defined in this line:

Comment: directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/postcard" + i);

Comment: Does the directory exist? I do not see where you are calling `mkdirs()` on it. Also, don't use concatenation: replace that with `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "postcard" + i);`

Comment: @CommonsWare I have already created other files on this directory without any problems, even received.txt itself. The directory exists in my mobile phone. I call mkdir() af few lines later. But ill change the concatenation, even though it shouldnt really matter.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that statement. The new file output stream will create the file.

Comment: @greenapps I just tried that, but it didnt remove or change the error sadly. Thanks for the suggestion